# Splitting byte string into columns

Tags: python

I have extracted some historical weather data and it's output in a large byte string format like:

ASN00040223194410TAVG  192H S  206H S  188H S  196H S  186H S  194H S  198H S  204H S  205H S  212H S  224H S  223H S  216H S  221H S  228H S  216H S  207H S  179H S  186H S  193H S  203H S  217H S  214H S  219H S  226H S  234H S  215H S  229H S  220H S  212H S  211H S

This string has a set format that I pulled apart using df.str.extract and then using a regex to match the pattern. For instance, the first 11 chars are the station ID, next 4 are the year, next 2 are the month, etc.

First question - is there an easier way to set up this parsing of the byte string? For example I'd like to be able to write a table like this:

| Name | Chars |
| --- | --- |
| StationID | 1-11 |
| Year | 12-15 |
| Month | 16-17 |
| Element | 18-21 |
| Value1 | 22-26 |
| Value2 | 27-31 |

and i want to turn that into a regular expression that gives me dataframe with each of the Names as columns like:

| StationID | Year | Month | Element | Value1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASN00xxx | 1994 | 10 | TMAX | 192 |

Ok, so part 2 of the question is after i have this dataframe i have columns with Value1, Flag1, Value2, Flag2 etc. These represent the values and flags for each day of the month. How can I turn each row with the year and month into separate rows with a datetime and their respective values:

| Date | TMAX | TAVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1994-10-01 | 10 | 7 |
| 1994-10-02 | 12 | 8 |

Comment: Where are you getting `Flag1` `Flag2` from?

Comment: Ask two separate questions please. Trim this one down to just one, and ask part 2 in another. In both cases, please show some sample code, and a sample input, maybe three lines trimmed down to the first 3-4 fields. I suspect there's a much faster way to do this, but I can only be sure with a [mcve]

Comment: @not_speshal, each data value comes with a couple of quality check flags like if data was missing or assumed etc. they're not important to what i'm doing but i need to split them out of the string anyway. For each day of the month there is a value, mflag, qflag, sflag. I just didn't type all that out in the question above

Comment: Let me know when you do. I'll take another look.

Comment: awesome, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507569/extract-daily-values-from-row-and-make-new-row-with-date

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you could write a custom function that converts the string passed to a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
def construct(string, config):
    d = dict()
    for name, chars in zip(config["Name"], config["Chars"]):
        start, end = [int(i) for i in chars.split("-")]
        d[name] = string[start-1:end].strip()
    return pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
```

Output:

```
string = "ASN00040223194410TAVG 192H S 206H S 188H S 196H S 186H S 194H S 198H S 204H S 205H S 212H S 224H S 223H S 216H S 221H S 228H S 216H S 207H S 179H S 186H S 193H S 203H S 217H S 214H S 219H S 226H S 234H S 215H S 229H S 220H S 212H S 211H S"

>>> config
        Name  Chars
0  StationID   1-11
1       Year  12-15
2      Month  16-17
3    Element  18-21
4     Value1  22-26
5     Value2  27-31

>>> construct(string, config)
     StationID  Year Month Element Value1 Value2
0  ASN00040223  1944    10    TAVG   192H   S 20
```