# Extract daily values from row and make new row with date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of weather data that I've compiled from a csv file byte string. Each line includes a month of data for one element, i.e. temp max in June 1949 is in the line where Year = 1949, Month = 06, Element = TMAX. The temp value for the 1st June is value1, 2nd June is value2 and so on.

I've copied to clipboard a snippet of the df and pasted below, you should be able to copy and use `pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')` to recreate this df.

What I need to do is extract the values for each day of the month (i'm not too worried about the mflag, sflag, qflag at this stage), attach the element the values refer to and make a new dataframe that looks like this:

| Date | TMAX | PRCP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1949-06-01 | 210 | 24 |
| 1949-06-02 | 189 | 36 |

```
,ID,year,month,element,value1,mflag1,qflag1,sflag1,value2,mflag2,qflag2,sflag2,value3,mflag3,qflag3,sflag3,value4,mflag4,qflag4,sflag4,value5,mflag5,qflag5,sflag5,value6,mflag6,qflag6,sflag6,value7,mflag7,qflag7,sflag7,value8,mflag8,qflag8,sflag8,value9,mflag9,qflag9,sflag9,value10,mflag10,qflag10,sflag10,value11,mflag11,qflag11,sflag11,value12,mflag12,qflag12,sflag12,value13,mflag13,qflag13,sflag13,value14,mflag14,qflag14,sflag14,value15,mflag15,qflag15,sflag15,value16,mflag16,qflag16,sflag16,value17,mflag17,qflag17,sflag17,value18,mflag18,qflag18,sflag18,value19,mflag19,qflag19,sflag19,value20,mflag20,qflag20,sflag20,value21,mflag21,qflag21,sflag21,value22,mflag22,qflag22,sflag22,value23,mflag23,qflag23,sflag23,value24,mflag24,qflag24,sflag24,value25,mflag25,qflag25,sflag25,value26,mflag26,qflag26,sflag26,value27,mflag27,qflag27,sflag27,value28,mflag28,qflag28,sflag28,value29,mflag29,qflag29,sflag29,value30,mflag30,qflag30,sflag30,value31,mflag31,qflag31,sflag31
14,40223,1945,12,TAVG,  244,H, ,S,  228,H, ,S,  239,H, ,S,  231,H, ,S,  195,H, ,S,  216,H, ,S,  232,H, ,S,  230,H, ,S,  253,H, ,S,  260,H, ,S,  251,H, ,S,  260,H, ,S,  256,H, ,S,  257,H, ,S,  252,H, ,S,  256,H, ,S,  253,H, ,S,  241,H, ,S,  209,H, ,S,  226,H, ,S,  229,H, ,S,  239,H, ,S,  239,H, ,S,  234,H, ,S,  233,H, ,S,  232,H, ,S,  234,H, ,S,  231,H, ,S,  232,H, ,S,  232,H, ,S,  241,H, ,S
15,40223,1946,01,TAVG,  249,H, ,S,  259,H, ,S,  256,H, ,S,  271,H, ,S,  277,H, ,S,  264,H, ,S,  231,H, ,S,  236,H, ,S,  235,H, ,S,  249,H, ,S,  257,H, ,S,  256,H, ,S,  250,H, ,S,  253,H, ,S,  261,H, ,S,  262,H, ,S,  257,H, ,S,  264,H, ,S,  264,H, ,S,  264,H, ,S,  272,H, ,S,  274,H, ,S,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , 
16,40223,1949,06,TMAX,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,  210, , ,a,  146, , ,a,  189, , ,a,  216, , ,a,  211, , ,a,  210, , ,a,  214, , ,a,  174, , ,a,  225, , ,a,  187, , ,a,  168, , ,a,  207, , ,a,  218, , ,a,  205, , ,a,  174, , ,a,  192, , ,a,  186, , ,a,  199, , ,a,  176, , ,a,  141, , ,a,  173, , ,a,  190, , ,a,  189, , ,a,  197, , ,a,  207, , ,a,  216, , ,a,  202, , ,a,  204, , ,a,-9999, , , 
17,40223,1949,06,TMIN,-9999, , , ,-9999, , , ,  136, , ,a,   60, , ,a,  113, , ,a,   84, , ,a,   91, , ,a,   88, , ,a,  126, , ,a,  131, , ,a,  129, , ,a,   84, , ,a,   81, , ,a,  113, , ,a,  110, , ,a,  133, , ,a,  136, , ,a,  108, , ,a,  111, , ,a,  122, , ,a,  107, , ,a,   81, , ,a,   59, , ,a,   57, , ,a,   44, , ,a,   42, , ,a,   66, , ,a,   77, , ,a,   60, , ,a,   68, , ,a,-9999, , , 
18,40223,1949,06,PRCP,  277, , ,a,  239, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    3, , ,a,   53, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    8, , ,a,    3, , ,a,    3, , ,a,   71, , ,a,  107, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,    0, , ,a,-9999, , , 
19,40223,1949,06,TAVG,  156,H, ,S,  174,H, ,S,  136,H, ,S,  129,H, ,S,  146,H, ,S,  153,H, ,S,  146,H, ,S,  165,H, ,S,  164,H, ,S,  154,H, ,S,  156,H, ,S,  126,H, ,S,  144,H, ,S,  153,H, ,S,  169,H, ,S,  167,H, ,S,  151,H, ,S,  154,H, ,S,  153,H, ,S,  150,H, ,S,  132,H, ,S,  102,H, ,S,  106,H, ,S,  109,H, ,S,  113,H, ,S,  121,H, ,S,  133,H, ,S,  132,H, ,S,  132,H, ,S,  129,H, ,S,-9999, , ,
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a more straightforward way to do what you want, but this code will work, and can be followed step by step.

Note, I saved the data in a file named `weather_data.csv` - using the clipboard wasn't quite working after a while.:)

```py
import pandas as pd

# df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
# df.to_csv('weather_data.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('weather_data.csv')

keep_columns = [col for col in df.columns[2:] if not 'flag' in col]
df = df[keep_columns]

df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['year', 'month', 'element'], value_vars=keep_columns[3:])

df_melt['day'] = df_melt['variable'].str[5:].astype(int)

df_melt = df_melt.query('value!=-9999')

df_melt['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_melt[['year', 'month', 'day']])
                              
df_final = df_melt[['date', 'element', 'value']].pivot(index='date', columns='element')

print(df_final)
```

Sample output:

```
          value
element     PRCP   TAVG   TMAX  TMIN
date
1945-12-01   NaN  244.0    NaN   NaN
1945-12-02   NaN  228.0    NaN   NaN
1945-12-03   NaN  239.0    NaN   NaN
1945-12-04   NaN  231.0    NaN   NaN
1945-12-05   NaN  195.0    NaN   NaN
...          ...    ...    ...   ...
1949-06-26   0.0  121.0  197.0  42.0
1949-06-27   0.0  133.0  207.0  66.0
1949-06-28   0.0  132.0  216.0  77.0
1949-06-29   0.0  132.0  202.0  60.0
1949-06-30   0.0  129.0  204.0  68.0
```

Comment: nice one, thanks!! I didn't know about pd.melt, appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's really a tedious task in terms writing the code to break down the structure you have.

Start by pivoting the dataframe you have passing `ID`, `year`, and `month` as index, `element` as column, and columns like `value1, value2,...` as values (you can use `DataFrame.filter` to get these values columns), then stack at level 0, take only `PRCP` and `TMAX` columns, then reset index at level -1.

Then extract the day values from level_3, (you can use regex `value(\d+)` to get day values, then reset the index at level 1 and 2.

Finally get the `Date` value out of `year`, `month`, and `day` columns.

```py
out=df.pivot(['ID', 'year',  'month'],
             ['element'],
             df.filter(like='value').columns).stack(0)[['PRCP', 'TMAX']].reset_index(-1)
out['day']=out['level_3'].str.extract('value(\d+)')
out = out.reset_index([1,2])
out['Date'] = pd.to_datetime((out['year']
                             .astype(str)
                            +out['month']
                            .astype(str).str.zfill(2)
                            +out['day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)),
              format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
element  year  month  level_3  PRCP   TMAX day       Date
ID                                                       
40223    1945     12   value1   NaN    NaN   1 1945-12-01
40223    1945     12  value10   NaN    NaN  10 1945-12-10
40223    1945     12  value11   NaN    NaN  11 1945-12-11
40223    1945     12  value12   NaN    NaN  12 1945-12-12
40223    1945     12  value13   NaN    NaN  13 1945-12-13
       ...    ...      ...   ...    ...  ..        ...
40223    1949      6   value5   0.0  189.0   5 1949-06-05
40223    1949      6   value6   0.0  216.0   6 1949-06-06
40223    1949      6   value7   0.0  211.0   7 1949-06-07
40223    1949      6   value8   0.0  210.0   8 1949-06-08
40223    1949      6   value9   3.0  214.0   9 1949-06-09
[93 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: nice one, legend! I need to read up on df.pivot. Yes it's very tedious, it's because the data comes from a large csv file where each month's values are stored in one long byte string. Am I going about the problem the wrong way maybe??

Comment: It's tedious in terms of writing the code to break down the structure you have, you can try above code once, it should work fine.